# bert sentence_transformers list index out of range

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, bert-language-model, sentence-transformers

I'm trying to use sentence_transformers to get bert embeddings, but it can't process for example 300 documents, i keep getting error **IndexError: list index out of range**. How to fix that?

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('distilbert-base-nli-mean-tokens')
embeddings = model.encode(tokenized_docs_smaller, show_progress_bar=True)
```

Comment: Would you please add the whole of what you've tried?

Comment: please add `tokenized_docs_smaller` codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to tokenize texts with BertTokenizer and not just use split()